# jython failed access to superclass

Tags: jython, superclass

```
class  InsertRemoveJTree( JTree ):
    def setModel( self, treeModel ):
    # for reasons I don't understand, the first call below results in infinite recursion... 
    # in other words the "super" approach returns this object, not its underlying base-class 
    # object.  The second approach works as expected
        # super( InsertRemoveJTree, self ).setModel( treeModel )
        JTree.setModel( self, treeModel )
```

anyone got any idea what this is about?  "setModel" is an attribute of the InsertRemoveJTree object as listed by dir().

Also many other methods from JTree work fine using the "super" approach.

I also tried going:

```
super(InsertRemoveJTree, self ).model = treeModel
```

... but it claimed there was no attr "model"

*Later*

I have come to the conclusion that this is a restriction due to the fact of calling a method on a pre-existing Java class, and that my statement "Also many other methods from JTree work fine using the "super" approach." is wrong.  There are some protected methods which are called by means of super_*XXX (e.g. DefaultTreeModel: super*_fireTreeNodesInserted) and which cause quite a few problems to a novice Jython user, until you start examining instances' attributes using dir( instance )).  But as a rule this appears to be a general restriction: i.e. you can't call the base class of a Java class subclassed in Jython using "super( PresentClass, self )..."

Answer (score 1):

Your first call means "Call the setModel defined in InsertRemoveJTree", ie a recursive call.
You want `super( JTree, self ).setModel( treeModel )` to call the one defined in JTree.
Here's the [Python doc for super](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super).

Comment: thanks for the answer ... but this isn't so.  Normally super( XXX, self ).yyy means "use the instance which is of class (superclass of XXX) to call its method yyy".  Otherwise you wouldn't need the "super" construct at all.  i.e. here you can easily go JTree.setModel( self, treeModel ). But super is meant to allow you not to have to spell out the name of the superclass